# Azure Container Instance Security VPN

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances, vnet

I've got an azure container instance... I've added it into a vnet... with a private IP address..10.0.0.4

I want only a handful of azure app services to be able to call the rest API that this azure container instance exposes, how do I give those azure app services the ability to call the container?

Cheers
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways in which you might achieve this.

One would be to [Configure a single public IP address for outbound and inbound traffic to an Azure container group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-egress-ip-address) With this method, you can [deploy an Azure Container Instance in a Virtual network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-egress-ip-address#deploy-aci-in-a-virtual-network) as you have already done.

Then,

##### Deploy Azure Firewall in network

First, use the [az network vnet subnet create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/vnet/subnet#az_network_vnet_subnet_create) to add a subnet named AzureFirewallSubnet for the firewall. AzureFirewallSubnet is the required name of this subnet.

```
az network vnet subnet create \
  --name AzureFirewallSubnet \
  --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME \
  --vnet-name $aci-vnet   \
  --address-prefix 10.0.1.0/26
```

Use the following [Azure CLI commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/firewall/deploy-cli) to create a firewall in the subnet.

If not already installed, add the firewall extension to the Azure CLI using the [az extension add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/extension#az_extension_add) command:

```
az extension add --name azure-firewall
```

Create the firewall resources:

```
az network firewall create \
  --name myFirewall \
  --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME \
  --location eastus

az network public-ip create \
  --name fw-pip \
  --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME \
  --location eastus \
  --allocation-method static \
  --sku standard
    
az network firewall ip-config create \
  --firewall-name myFirewall \
  --name FW-config \
  --public-ip-address fw-pip \
  --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME \
  --vnet-name $aci-vnet
```

Update the firewall configuration using the [az network firewall update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/firewall#az_network_firewall_update) command:

```
az network firewall update \
  --name myFirewall \
  --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME
```

Get the firewall's private IP address using the [az network firewall ip-config list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/firewall/ip-config#az_network_firewall_ip_config_list) command. This private IP address is used in a later command.

```
FW_PRIVATE_IP="$(az network firewall ip-config list \
  --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME \
  --firewall-name myFirewall \
  --query "[].privateIpAddress" --output tsv)"
```

Get the firewall's public IP address using the [az network public-ip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/public-ip/#az_network_public_ip_show) show command. This public IP address is used in a later command.

```
FW_PUBLIC_IP="$(az network public-ip show \
  --name fw-pip \
  --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME \
  --query ipAddress --output tsv)"
```

##### Define user-defined route on ACI subnet

Define a use-defined route on the ACI subnet, to divert traffic to the Azure firewall. For more information, see [Route network traffic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/tutorial-create-route-table-cli).

###### Create Route Table

First, run the following [az network route-table create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/route-table/#az_network_route_table_create) command to create the route table. Create the route table in the same region as the virtual network.

```
az network route-table create \
  --name Firewall-rt-table \
  --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME \
  --location eastus \
  --disable-bgp-route-propagation true
```

###### Create route

Run [az network-route-table route create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/route-table/route#az_network_route_table_route_create) to create a route in the route table. To route traffic to the firewall, set the next hop type to `VirtualAppliance`, and pass the firewall's private IP address as the next hop address.

```
az network route-table route create \
  --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME \
  --name DG-Route \
  --route-table-name Firewall-rt-table \
  --address-prefix 0.0.0.0/0 \
  --next-hop-type VirtualAppliance \
  --next-hop-ip-address $FW_PRIVATE_IP
```

###### Associate route table to ACI subnet

Run the [az network vnet subnet update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/vnet/subnet#az_network_vnet_subnet_update) command to associate the route table with the subnet delegated to Azure Container Instances.

```
az network vnet subnet update \
  --name $aci-subnet \
  --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME \
  --vnet-name $aci-vnet \
  --address-prefixes 10.0.0.0/24 \
  --route-table Firewall-rt-table
```

Finally,

##### Configure rules on firewall

By default, Azure Firewall denies (blocks) inbound and outbound traffic.

###### Configure NAT rule on firewall to ACI subnet

Create a [NAT rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/firewall/rule-processing) on the firewall to translate and filter inbound internet traffic to the application container you started previously in the network. For details, see [Filter inbound Internet traffic with Azure Firewall DNAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/firewall/tutorial-firewall-dnat)

Create a NAT rule and collection by using the [az network firewall nat-rule create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/firewall/nat-rule#az_network_firewall_nat_rule_create) command:

```
az network firewall nat-rule create \
  --firewall-name myFirewall \
  --collection-name myNATCollection \
  --action dnat \
  --name myRule \
  --protocols TCP \
  --source-addresses '$SOURCE_ADDRESSES' \
  --destination-addresses $FW_PUBLIC_IP \
  --destination-ports 80 \
  --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME \
  --translated-address $ACI_PRIVATE_IP \
  --translated-port 80 \
  --priority 200
```

Add NAT rules as needed to filter traffic to other IP addresses in the subnet. For example, other container groups in the subnet could expose IP addresses for inbound traffic, or other internal IP addresses could be assigned to the container group after a restart.

**Note:** Replace $SOURCE_ADDRESSES with a space-separated list of your [App Services' outbound IP Addresses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/networking-features#outbound-addresses).

###### Create outbound application rule on the firewall

Run the following [az network firewall application-rule creat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/firewall/application-rule#az_network_firewall_application_rule_create)e command to create an outbound rule on the firewall. This sample rule allows access from the subnet delegated to Azure Container Instances to the FQDN `checkip.dyndns.org`. HTTP access to the site is used in a later step to confirm the egress IP address from Azure Container Instances.

```
az network firewall application-rule create \
  --collection-name myAppCollection \
  --firewall-name myFirewall \
  --name Allow-CheckIP \
  --protocols Http=80 Https=443 \
  --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME \
  --target-fqdns checkip.dyndns.org \
  --source-addresses 10.0.0.0/24 \
  --priority 200 \
  --action Allow
```

---

An alternative method can be to [Integrate your App Service with an Azure virtual network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet). With [Azure Virtual Network (VNets)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-overview), you can place many of your Azure resources in a non-internet-routable network. The VNet Integration feature enables your apps to access resources in or through a VNet. **VNet Integration doesn't enable your apps to be accessed privately**.

Please find a pictorial example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#enable-vnet-integration). You can then connect the the App Service virtual Network with the ACI Virtual Network through [Vnet-toVnet peering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/tutorial-connect-virtual-networks-portal) or [Vnet-to-Vnet VPN Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-vnet-vnet-resource-manager-portal)

However, with this method, you will have to integrate all the Azure App Services that will be connecting to your ACI with a Virtual Network.